# How can I inhibit the effect of hitting Ctrl+Menu

Tags: escape, keyboard-layout

I'm referring to holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hitting <kbd>Menu</kbd> (which is [this key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)), which happens by mistake sometimes.

For me it results in going back to normal mode and moving to the first non-blank character of the line.

Indeed, if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Menu</kbd> (in command line mode or insert mode), what I see is `^[[29^`, where the first two chars `^[` are one atom (the same that is generated also by <kbd>Escape</kbd>), and the following are single chars. So I kind of understand why the combination reults in "go back to normal mode, `^[`, and then to the first non-blank character, `^`.

But how can I get rid of this behavior without impacting anything else?

---

I asked a follow up question [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/38922/6498).

Comment: Maybe could you try to map that <kbd>Menu</kbd> key to another key. e.g. ``:set <S-Down>=^[[29^``

Comment: Or you could try to map the sequence to ``<Nop>``: ``map ^[[29^ <Nop>``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose you to map the key sequence `^[[29^` to `<Nop>`

```
:noremap ^[[29^ <Nop>
```