# lnoremap doesn't seem to apply to insert mode when mapping an unwanted key combo to nop

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, insert-mode, escape

This is a follow up to [this question of mine](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37623/how-can-i-inhibit-the-effect-of-hitting-ctrlmenu).

I found out that having `:noremap ^[[29^ <Nop>` in my vimrc is not enough to disable the unwanted effect of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Menu</kbd> in insert mode, so I looked at [`:help map-table`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#map-table) and verified that indeed `:noremap` does not apply to insert mode.

Therefore I decided to make the least number of mappings to disable that key combo on every mode. Based on that table this seemed a good combination:

```
lnoremap ^[[29^      <NOP>
noremap  ^[[29^      <NOP>
tnoremap ^[[29^      <NOP>
```

(where clearly `^[` is obtained via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Escape</kbd>).

But apparently `lnoremap` is not applying to insert mode! You can see it in the screencast below.

Am I misunderstanding `map-table` information concerning `lnoremap`, or is it a bug I should report?

I wonder whether the last paragraph of [`language-mapping`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#language-mapping) is relevant in this respect,

> Language mappings will never be applied to already mapped characters. They are only used for typed characters.  This assumes that the language mapping was already done when typing the mapping.

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `l` in `:lmap` is for "language". `:lmap` is only effective when an input method is set. See `:help 'iminsert'` and related options.

If you want to cover the most modes with the least number of commands, you will need the following lines:

```
" Normal, Visual, Select, Operator-pending
noremap  ^[[29^ <NOP>
" Insert and Command-line
noremap! ^[[29^ <NOP>
" Terminal-Job
tnoremap ^[[29^ <NOP>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
:inoremap … <Nop>
```

But be careful with mappings with `<esc>` in the left-hand-side.

Comment: :( Sorry for not being clear. My point was that if want to cover all modes, `inoremap`+`noremap`+`tnoremap` still don't do it.

Comment: So yes, I know of `inoremap`, but why isn't `lnoremap` doing it if the doc says it applies to insert mode too?